# ¿Como cambiar texto de label con delay y en otro thread?

Tags: swift, swift2, hilos

Como bien dice la pregunta, necesito cambiar el texto de 4 diferentes labels sin que la vista se quede sin poder procesar otros procesos y además entre estos cambios de texto necesito un delay de al menos 1 segundo.
Ya intente hacerlo en un async block pero desde ahí no puedo modificar la `UI` seguramente como medida de precaución de `race condition`.

Add:
Por ahora tengo este código pero sigo sin poder cambiar dormir y cambiar el título del boton al segundo.

```
    func startPings() {                      

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), {
                for boton in self.botones {
                    //print("Durmió")
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        boton.setTitle("<->", forState: .Normal)
                    })
                }
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la siguiente extensión:

```
extension NSObject {

    func delay(seconds: Double, fire:() -> ()) {

        let delay = seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
        dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), fire)

    }

}
```

Después, podrás utilizarla en cualquier lugar de tu código de la siguiente manera:

```
self.delay(1.0, fire: {

    for boton in self.botones {
        boton.setTitle("<->", forState: .Normal)
    }

})
```

Comment: Mmm buen código pero con el delay, el thread sigue su ejecución y nesecito que no lo haga :(

Comment: En la pregunta original has puesto 'sin que la vista se quede sin poder procesar otros procesos' y eso precisamente es lo que hace. Si haces los cambios síncronos bloquearas las interfaz y la experiencia de usuario será muy mala...

Comment: Mhergon, tenes razón, me explique un poco mal.

Answer (score 0):

```
func startPings() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
        for boton in self.botones {
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                boton.setTitle("<.>", forState: .Normal)
            })
            sleep(2)
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                boton.setTitle("", forState: .Normal)
            })


        }
    })
}
```

Código que anduvo.